# Basic Swift grammar

Tags: swift

```
@IBAction func inputformula(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let formulaText = formulalabel.text else {
        return
    }
    guard let senderedText = sender.titleLabel.text else {
        return
    }
    formulaLabel.text = formulaText + senderedText
}
```

I can't understand the grammar in the text below.

```
guard let senderedText = sender.titleLabel.text else
```

what is `sender.titleLabel`?

If you have any helpful URL, please let me know.

Comment: Check this [Guard Statements](https://thatthinginswift.com/guard-statement-swift/)

Comment: Don't conflate Swift, the language, with iOS, the platform, and UIKit, the framework for doing UI stuff on iOS. Labels and text fields are in UIKit and you access them with Swift but they are not in Swift itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not compile. `sender` is `Any`, so you can't access the property `titleLabel` directly. You either have to write:

```
guard let senderedText = (sender as? UIButton)?.titleLabel?.text else {
    return
}
```

Or change the parameter type:

```
@IBAction func inputformula(_ sender: UIButton) {
```

As you can see, I inferred `sender` to be a `UIButton` because [`UIButton` has a `titleLabel` property.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel) Hopefully this is what you are confused about.

The guard statement checks whether the text of the button is nil. If it is, return, otherwise carry on.

Comment: Better yet - change `Any` to `UIButton` in the method signature.

Comment: @maddy It's not *necessarily* better to change the sender type. The sender of an action does not have to be a button.

Comment: @JeremyP Then make `sender` match whatever the appropriate type needs to be. `Any` is very rarely the right choice for `sender`.

Comment: @maddy If any object can call the sender (and it can, if you want to invoke the sender programmatically) then `Any` is the appropriate type. It's a reasonable equivalent to using `id` in Objective-C.

Comment: @JeremyP First, my username is `rmaddy`, not `maddy`. How often do you connect an `IBAction` to multiple *types* of controls? It may be connected to multiple `UIButton`, but would you have it connected to a `UIButton` and `UIBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what you are trying to ask, but...
you are asking what `sender.titleLabel` is: I think your action is triggered by a button. If I am correct here your sender is your button, what means `sender.titleLabel` is the title of your sender (i.e. button) 
Useful resources could be:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel

Maybe you first want to get into the basics:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit